# How to bind li tag with its child a tag?

Tags: jquery

I want the DOM to consider that the anchor tag is clicked even when the user click on it's parent li element in which anchor tag resides.

```
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Here link "test1" works only when I click on the text but when I click over li tag I want the link to go to target page.

Comment: Note that probably setting your `a` to `display:block` completely filling the `li` likely negates the need for javascript to achieve this. A bit of CSS fiddling perhaps, but not much.

Answer (score 1):

#### Note

you can try with CSS `display:block` to `a` tag first. I think `a` tag is not taking all available space to `li`. So you have this problem.

---

#### If CSS fail then

```
$("ul li").click(function(){
   window.location = $(this).find("a").attr('href');
});
```

You are trying to make a click to link, tag but it's not possible in general way because click is not default event with anchor tag.

You can do that if you bind an `click` handler to `a` tag before and fire that later like following:

```
$('ul li a').on('click', function() {
  window.location = this.href;
});

$("ul li").click(function(){
   $(this).find("a").click(); // fire previous click event binded to anchor
});
```

Comment: Is there any other way  without using window.location. Because this anchor tag has onclick="jsp tag" and href="#"?

Comment: I want do it with jQuery using bind, click or other jquery api but not using CSS or jQuery CSS.

Comment: @RajMehta if you want to page reload I think you have to go for `window.location`